# order of an integral on the real line

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

How to prove that, the following integral, $d \in \mathbb{N}$, $d > 1$,

$$
\int_{n^{1/4}}^{\infty} x^{d-1} \exp(-x^2) \, dx
$$

is of order $O(n^{\frac{d-1}{4}} \exp(-n^{1/2}) ) $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts after substituting $x\mapsto x^{1/2}$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{n^{1/4}}^\infty x^{d-1}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{n^{1/2}}^\infty x^{d/2-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\left(n^{d/4-1/2}e^{-n^{1/2}}-\left(\frac d2-1\right)\int_{n^{1/2}}^\infty x^{d/2-2}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac12n^{d/4-1/2}e^{-n^{1/2}}\left(1+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\right)}
\end{align}
$$
since
$$
\int_{n^{1/2}}^\infty x^{d/2-2}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\le n^{-1/2}\int_{n^{1/2}}^\infty x^{d/2-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Furthermore
$$
\frac12n^{d/4-1/2}e^{-n^{1/2}}=O\left(n^{d/4-1/4}e^{-n^{1/2}}\right)
$$